# Xamarin Android programming in vs 2015

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm using vs 2015 to make android project with xamarin. i see this error in first of new project. please help me

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqXhy.jpg)

Comment: did you change the adroid sdk diretory ?

Comment: This could happen when you are not installed or remove or change the android SDK directory.